# How to attach PDF using \includepdf without losing editable data?

Tags: pdftex, pdfpages

I am attaching some PDF to my document using \includepdf, some pages of which have comment data which might have added while creating original PDF.

Now for generated PDF that comment data is missing. Is there any way to keep it intact while attaching using \includepdf?

Tried the way printing and saving it again as PDF. It works but not so convenient in my case as I have thousands of indivisual such files. Please help.

Comment: Could you be more specific about your workflow :. How do you created these PDF? Are they regular PDF forms ?, Why do you want to attach them. Notice that `\includepdf` emded the pdf and handle it as an image ( it is based on `\includegraphics`) and does not create an "attachment". Such an attachment could be created with `hyperref`, but is not handled by all the PDF reading tools.

Comment: The included pages are treated as images so form data is lost, as is internal hyperlinks.